# XPage with Notes Calendar Store and iNotes Calendar accessed anonymously show error

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I have a non anonymous http Domino server (9.0.1 FP10 HF197), but

```
HTTPPublicURL=/dwaredir.nsf/*:/public/*:/xsp/.ibmxspres/*
```

(The third elem is a test, no difference to the following behavior)

DB in path /public/.....nsf
Xpage=Allowed Public Access

- If DB ACL Anonymous=no access, require login, all run fine, calendar show data
- If DB ACL Anonymous=reader, user show calendar empty and get the error
  [image]

In XPage I have only a CC that contains
- Notes Calendar Store
- iNotes Calendar
- some stuff as images like the following:
selectedImage="/.ibmxspres/.extlib/icons/calendar/1_Day_selected_24.gif"

**Problem:**
The XPage read calendar data from company's Resource Reservation DB, that needs to be anonymous=no access. When I set RR DB anonymous=reader, then I can data without error, but when the RR DB is Anonymous=no access, then I got the error.

There is no way to reproduce in teamroom app, because the data are inside the same application.

**Question:**
Is there a way to allow Notes Calendar Store and iNotes Calendar to a data DB that is not anonymously accessible for an anonymous user?

Comment: The following reply is not a true solution, anywhere it is enough: this Domino setup does not allow to browse Resource Reservation DB data anonymously (http port anonymous=no). The only public folder is the one specified in HTTPPublicUrl, this contain true anonymous xpage. So in this particular Domino setup ACL Anonymous in RR DB can be reader. 

**Still Anonymous access of Notes Calendar Store to not anonymous data DB is an issue**.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of that you could do that is by writing an agent that accesses the data. The agent would be configured to run with the identity of the signer, and the signer would need to have access rights, but the agent itself could be in an NSF that is accessible to Anonymous.

Comment: I can't imagine an agent that works and give data as do a Calendar Data Store and json data source.

Comment: In that case I think the answer to your question is going to be no, because I'm not aware of any other way to give an anonymous user access to data that is protected by an ACL that denies access to Anonymous.